# Using pasted text in return in user written functions

Tags: r, function, return-value

I've written a simple example of the problem I am facing. I have a function that creates multiple objects storing values and I would like to return all of those values. In my real life example the number of objects vary and are data dependent. Because of that I would like to create a vector containing the names of all of the objects I would like returned and then evaluate that vector so that all of those objects are returned when the function is called. I am not able to figure out how to do so.

Here is simple syntax that demonstrates the problem (and how I've attempted to solve it):

```
v1=runif(50)

takemean1=function(x){
  avg=mean(x)
  std=sd(x)
  return(c(avg,std))
}

text=c("avg","std")

takemean2=function(x){
  avg=mean(x)
  std=sd(x)
  return(c(eval(parse(text=noquote(paste(text))))))
}

takemean1(v1)
takemean2(v1)
```

takemean1 produces the desired output while takemean2 only returns std, it does not return avg. How do I need to adjust my approach so that takemean2 produces the same output as takemean1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mget`:

```r
v1 = runif(50)

text = c("avg", "std")

takemean2 = function(x) {
  avg = mean(x)
  std = sd(x)
  unlist(mget(text))
}

takemean2(v1)
#>       avg       std 
#> 0.4645234 0.2681609
```